# VSCode "Cannot read property 'openConfigFile' of undefined"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I was recently coding in VSCode, the problem happened when I loaded my program.
It said "Cannot read property 'openConfigFile' of undefined".

I do have the C++ extension.

Here is the image:
[img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAWJ3.png)

Also, about the tasks configuration, it says I need a workspace folder, but I can't choose "Workspace" in the extension context menu. Image:
[Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40iAk.png),
[Context Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGnN4.png)

Comment: I resolved this error for a similar issue for myself by adding a `.vscode` directory in the root of my open workspace